# Fetch not receiving error message from Node Js

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

What's happening:

My project has a route called `/login`, when an user to try do login and he is not "MANAGER" (attribute of the database), it should give a 401 error. In the back-end it is working but the `error` is not received in the fetch of the front-end, I don't know why.

My code Node.js:

```js
const {
  findByMail
} = require('../data/acl/acl.model');

module.exports =
  async function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    const acl = await findByMail(req.body.username);

    if (acl && acl.role !== "MANAGER") {
      res.status(401).send("You dont have access")
    }

    next()
  }
```

My front-end:

```js
handleLogin = async() => {
  try {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });

    const rawResponse = await fetch('/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ ...this.state
      }),
    });

    const response = await rawResponse.json();

    localStorage.setItem('user-token', response.token);
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    });
  } catch (err) {
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    });
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Console.log:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0
at Login._callee$ (login.js:18)
at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:296)
at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:103406:21)
at step (background.login.png:1)
at background.login.png:1

login.js:18 POST https://localhost:3000/login 401 ()
```

I don't know what's wrong, could somebody help me?

Comment: Try to debug your json if it's in correct format

Comment: Already did, it do the fetch correctly but when arrives in the `catch` the mesage of error not work.

Comment: You tried debugging this line body: JSON.stringify({ ...this.state
      }),

Comment: what does your response look like?

Comment: Some code somewhere is trying to parse something that starts with "F" as JSON, and that's not valid JSON. You'll need to inspect the result of the request in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: `fetch` returns a promise, which means you can add `.catch()` to it to catch any errors raised during execution of the promise.  I don't believe these will be caught by a `catch` block in a try/catch.  Follow the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) that uses the `.catch()` functionality. Looks like this could be a separate issue, though, based on what r3zaxd1 posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple, fetch() doesn't recognize a 401 code as an unacceptable response so your catch will not be called, instead it will continue the code like a 200 code.

After you got the response you should do this :

```
handleLogin = async() => {
  try {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });

    const rawResponse = await fetch('/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ ...this.state
      }),
    });

    if(!rawResponse.ok){
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
    }
    else{
      const response = await rawResponse.json();

      localStorage.setItem('user-token', response.token);
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
    }

  } catch (err) {
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    });
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello friend, thank your to answer, i put that inside `{catch (err) {your code}`?

Comment: I did this:
`catch (err) {
      if (!err.ok) {
        console.log(err.status)
      }`

And the return was `undefined`, why

Comment: I edited my answer and added a working sample based on your code.

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? do you get any error ?

Comment: The return is `undefined`